# Creality Ender 6 Heating failed error

Tags: creality-ender-6, creality

I got this message from my Creality Ender 6 printer.

Now every time I want to print, or when it heats up, the printer gives me this message.

Can anyone please help with this?

[image: Heating failed error]

Comment: You need to figure out if the problem is (physically) related to nozzle, the bed, or both, or none. Surroundings / conditions could be of importance. Coud you include information where do you use the printer? Is there relatively warm (like apartment) or rather cold (like basement, or tin garage in winter)? Do you have drafts? etc. Otherwise it could be electronics: do you feel any notions of heating when you touch the bed or (much more carefully!) the nozzle?

Comment: This is a Thermal Runaway Eror. We need more information, best a temperature graph.

Comment: Sorry, but this question cannot be answered, this question needs more information to be able to be answered. Troubleshooting the cause, you should create some G-code files where you e.g. heat up only the bed [`M190`](https://reprap.org/wiki/G-code#M190:_Wait_for_bed_temperature_to_reach_target_temp) or only the hot end [`M109`](https://reprap.org/wiki/G-code#M109:_Set_Extruder_Temperature_and_Wait), or heat up the hot end and turn on the fan [`M106`](https://reprap.org/wiki/G-code#M106:_Fan_On), etc...

Comment: I have the same error with the same ender 6. I noticed that the bead heats up fine, but the nozzle does not heat up at all. The room itself is relatively cool. about 22 degs C with zero draft. The printer has printed in this room before with no issues. This has only started to occur in the last week. It was printing fine, I came to check about a third of the way into the print and had the heating failure. Not sure what do from this point on. any advice would be grateful.

Comment: Hi, did you solve your issue? If so, please post the answer as others seem to have the same issue. Otherwise, please provide more details, as @0scar requests, so that an accurate solution can be provided. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen a version of this error on my Ender 3 when I heated the hot end without the silicone sock (or any other insulating wrap).

If this occurred after changing a nozzle, replacing a heat break (or entire hot end), installing a new cooling duct, or similar, it's likely you just inadvertently left off the insulation that should surround the heat block, making it take much longer and require much more power to reach working temperature than is normal.

This can also occur if the thermistor or heater cartridge are not correctly seated in the heat block -- the same problems that can result in a thermal runaway halt (assuming your printer has that feature) if it does get to temperature before timing out.

Answer (score 0):

Someone with experience using an Ender may give a more specific answer to you question.  This is a general answer, not for a specific model.

"Soon enough" is saying the printer timed out before reaching temperature.

1. Do you see the temperature increasing on both the hot end and bed?  If one doesn't, that's where the failure occurs.
2. Are you setting a temperature higher than you have ever used on this printer?  If so, check to see if you are beyond the printers capability.
3. The hotend will reach temperature first. Does it reach the target temperature? If so, the issue is probably with your bed heater.  If not, the issue is with your hot end.
4. If you are pushing the extremes of your heaters, especially the bed heater, and your printer isn't in an enclose, you may need and enclosure to run that temperature.

Once you determine where the issue is at, there are things to can do to determine what is failing.